# spinner for each component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best practice and efficient way for implement spinner component for whole apps ?

My sample code :

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loading)
    return (
      <Spinner/>
    )

  return (
    <div className="container">
  )
}
```

i want avoid to rewrite the same logic checking *loading* state for each component. 
TIA.

Comment: Trying to avoid duplicating a single `if` seems like over-optimisation to me, and you'll probably just end up making your project more complicated by trying to avoid it.

Comment: This is an opinionated question. Ternary or if...else both are conditional statements and will be very similar in performance. Also, this looks like micro optimization. Instead look at the logic and optimize that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a utils folder and make a file (sppiner.js)
in that file and write this code

> spinner.js

```
export default function spinner({text}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Spinner/>
      <span>{text}</span>
    </div>
  )
```

and after that in each component that you want use spinner  write this code

```
import Spinner from "utils/spinner";

return(
...
{this.state.loading && <Spinner text={"your text..."} />}
...
)
```

Comment: ok your wellcome if you like this answer please accept it thank you @cumibulat

Answer (score 2):

Simply apply a ternary:

```
render() {
  return this.state.loading ? <Spinner/> : <App />
}
```

And make it a function:

loader.js

```
import Spinner from './spinner.js';
export default function LoadManager = ({loading}) => props.loading ? <Spinner /> : props.children;
```

So in your components

```
render() {
  return 
    <LoadManager loading={this.state.loading}>
      <App />
    </LoadManager>
}
```

Other more common ways involves use of React Loadable:

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import Loading from './my-loading-component';

const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./my-component'),
  loading: Loading,
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoadableComponent/>;
  }
```

This is more efficient too, has the code will be splitted.

Comment: How is this more efficient?

Comment: This is simply cleaner, with a single return and no if, cause the condition has only 2 possible output based on a boolean

Comment: Correct! This is the same code written in different style. So basically its not resolving anything. If OP is not satisfied with performance of `if...else`, this is going to be same. You may say about bundle size as it will take less lines but the if you use bundler like webpack/ gulp, that's done automatically. So the code should be more readable instead

Comment: @Rajesh the OP simple wants to do not repeat the code ore make it less heavy to bring in other components. There is no code splitting issues or performances involved.

Comment: The whole App component with all children will be re-renderer if spinner toggles. It will impact performance a lot., @mohammad answer is more efficient.

Comment: As I suppose the loading happens once, this is not a problem. In @mohammad response the spinner is shown along with the whole component, and that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: thanks guys for your input, i will try the approach and looks whats the best for my project :)

Answer (score 1):

What about adding this kind of function?

```
function renderSpinner() {
  return this.state.loading && <Spinner />
}
```

Comment: Notice that with `&&` operator, the _right part_ of the operator is evaluated only if the first is truthy, otherwise the _left part_ will be returned. In this case it would render _false_ if loading is false, if loading is _0_ it will render "0" as string.